# How do I retrieve all records through a TDatasetProvider?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

If I have two datasets that are both descended from `TCustomClientDataset`, I can have one call `CloneCursor` on the other, and have an independent view of the same data.  The documentation makes it appear that you can achieve essentially the same thing by using a `TDatasetProvider`, except that the source dataset can be any dataset.

I'm trying to make this work.  I have a `TSimpleDataset` (let's call it `A`) that reads data from a database, and a TClientDataset (let's call it `B`) that works with a separate view of it, and there's a `TDBGrid` connected to `B`.

If I call `B.CloneCursor(A, ...)`, the grid displays all the records in `A`.  But if I create a `TDatasetProvider` and set its `Dataset` property to `A`, and then set it as the provider for `B`, the grid connected to `B` only displays one row, instead of all of them.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it so that the grid will end up displaying all of `A`?

Comment: No problem here with your second approach. I tried a `TADODataSet` as well as a `TSimpleDataSet` for `A`.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of poking around in the debugger, I managed to track this down.  Opening the dataset pulls data through the provider, but it does not call `First` on the source dataset first.  Because of something elsewhere in the program, the source dataset had been on the last row, so I only got one row before it hit `EOF`.  Explicitly calling `First` beforehand fixes the problem.

Comment: Gosh, not sure whether to call this a bug or a feature. Something to be said for both I guess...